# Number increment with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i use the code below to display variable increment without affecting eachother, i tried to use the script on the same page to display different values that increases overtime but i get the same values in div1 and div2 even thought they have different var, the code below works fine when i use them on seperate pages but when i put them together on the same page i get same result for both div.

i need help to make them work without affecting eachother or any other alternative

i need code that actually works, not just explanation

```js
<script>
    var START_DATE = new Date("May 10, 2010 22:30:00");
    var INTERVAL = 8;
    var INCREMENT = 60;
    var START_VALUE = 250;
    var count = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
     var now = new Date();
     count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
     $('#div1').html(count.toFixed(0));
     window.setInterval( function(){
        count1 += INCREMENT; 
        $('#div1').html(count.toFixed(0));
     }, msInterval);
    });
    </script>

  <script>
    var START_DATE = new Date("March 10, 2010 22:30:00");
    var INTERVAL = 10;
    var INCREMENT = 10;
    var START_VALUE = 350;
    var count = 0;
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
     var now = new Date();
     count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
     $('#div2').html(count.toFixed(0));
     window.setInterval( function(){
        count1 += INCREMENT; 
        $('#div2').html(count.toFixed(0));
     }, msInterval);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: They're the same variable because you are declaring them in the global scope

Comment: can you help with this solution of your using the code presented above? @Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although dzylich's answers is correct, here is a more thorough explanation of what's happening:

Javascript has one global scope with no knowledge of modules or namespaces. Any `var` declared in the top scope of a `script` tag is in the global namespace, so your code runs as if you had written:

```
var count1 = whatever;
//do some stuff
var count1 = whatever; //count1 redeclared!
```

in the same `script`. One common method to avoid this problem is to wrap each piece of code in an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) (IIFE) to create a scope for each script tag:

```
<script>
  (function() {
      var counter1 = whatever;
      //do stuff to counter1
  })();
</script>

<script>
  (function() {
     var counter1 = whatever; //different than the other counter1, exp follows
     //do whatever
  })();
</script>
```

Because each chunk of code is wrapped in a function (which creates a new scope for `var`s defined in that function) the two 'counter1's are actually different variables. Note that you can't access things in one IIFE wrapped block in another unless you explicitly return them, see the [revealing module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).

Comment: Thanks for better explanation, i have been bumping my ass the whole day to get this done, i am not that good with javascript

Comment: No problem. Understanding of scope (and the related mechanics of the `this` pointer) are two of the most confusing things in javascript because they differ from other languages in subtle ways. Half of your time coding in any language is pretty invariably relegated to working around its inadequacies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could wrap the code blocks in IFEE, i.e.

```
(function(){
    //code here
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `count` declarations are overwriting each other. Change the name of one of your `count` variables and it should work.

Comment: can you help with this solution of your using the code presented above?

Comment: You don't need an example, just change the name of one of the count variables to count1. I see you've only changed one of the instances.